# IAR Workbench color customization

Tags: ide, stm32, iar

I'm new to IAR Workbench (i use version 8.40) and I find the lack of color customization options quite confusing.

I'd like to apply different colors to functions and variables, so for example variables red and functions blue.
I tried to search into Options > Editor > Colors and Fonts but couldn't find anything useful.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately color customization in IAR EW is quite limited. It's a little better in later versions, but even then function and variable names are classified as identifiers and use the same color.

If you want better syntax highlighting, you need to use different editor. Personally I use IAR EW for project management, building and debugging, but use more suitable text editor for writing the code.